# BibTex: Modify punctuation marks around MR number

Tags: bibtex, amsplain

I am using BibTeX, with the class amsart and for the bibliography style I am using amsplain. Moreover, I download my citations from Mathematical Reviews.

**My problem is the following**: Currently, at the end of the references, BibTeX adds a period before the MR number and nothing after. However, I would prefer to have a comma before the MR number and a period after it. Hence instead of having e.g.:

> Michael B. Green, John H. Schwarz, and Edward Witten, Superstring theory.
>   Vol. 1, second ed., Cambridge Monographs on Mathematical Physics,
>   Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1988, Introduction. MR952374

I would prefer to have:

> Michael B. Green, John H. Schwarz, and Edward Witten, Superstring theory.
>   Vol. 1, second ed., Cambridge Monographs on Mathematical Physics,
>   Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1988, Introduction, MR952374.

I tried to modify amsplain but only got error messages. What code should I use to get the desired effect?

---

**In my BibTeX File, (test.bib) I have the following entry:**

```
@book {MR952374,
AUTHOR = {Green, Michael B. and Schwarz, John H. and Witten, Edward},
TITLE = {Superstring theory. {V}ol. 1},
SERIES = {Cambridge Monographs on Mathematical Physics},
EDITION = {Second},
NOTE = {Introduction},
PUBLISHER = {Cambridge University Press, Cambridge},
YEAR = {1988},
PAGES = {x+470},
ISBN = {0-521-35752-7},
MRCLASS = {81-02 (81E30 81Exx 83-02 83E30 83Exx)},
MRNUMBER = {952374},
}
```

**And in my .tex file I have this:**

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsart}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{lmodern}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\cite{MR952374}    

\bibliographystyle{amsplain}    
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

---

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please post a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that shows this behavior so that we can run tests to modify the style for you?

Comment: Dear Phelype, thank you, wait for me a minute. I will add it.

Comment: I'm not sure what a comma would mean between the note field and the MR number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one was quite tricky (read: *fun*).

One way to (partially) solve your problem would be to redefine the `\MR` macro, which is used by `amsplain` to typeset the `MR` number:

```
\long\def\MR#1{%
  \relax
  \ifhmode
    \unskip
    \spacefactor 3000
    \space
  \fi%              ↓ dot added here
  MR~\MRhref{#1}{#1}.}
```

(which is the same as the original definition, but with a period at the end).

The problem with this approach is that the end of the reference would be typeset as:

```
Press, Cambridge, 1988, Introduction. MR952374.
```

If you don't mind the period after "Introduction" then whis is the way to go. The next approach is a little messy...

---

TeX doesn't offer (as far as I know --- someone please tell me how if I'm wrong) the possibility to *un*-write something, so it is not possible to remove the comma that follows "Introduction" in case the `MR` number is present. So we have to change the BeaST!

Around the line 300 of `amsplain.bst` we have two functions:

```
FUNCTION {output.nonempty.mrnumber}
```

which will, as the name says, output a nonempty `MR` number, and:

```
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
```

which finishes each bibliography entry. We'll need to change two things:

1. Make `fin.entry` *not* write a period at the end of the entry.
2. make `output.nonempty.mrnumber` write `, MR<number>.` or `.` if there is or there is not an `MR` number.

The modified functions are:

```
FUNCTION {output.nonempty.mrnumber}
{ duplicate$ missing$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "." write$ }
    { ", \MR{" swap$ * "}." * write$ }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ write$
  mrnumber output.nonempty.mrnumber
  newline$
}
```

You just have to make a copy of `amsplain.bst` to your working directory and replace `output.nonempty.mrnumber` and `fin.entry` to the versions above.

The reference is now typeset properly, and it also works when there is no `MR` number:

[image]